# Calculate hex color with transparency based on other colors

Tags: colors, hex, calculation

I have the following image:

[image: image example]

*I want to find the hex color and transparency of the red circle based on the below information :*

- purple background circle is **#afb0cc**
- human figure is **#ffffff**

By using eye-dropper I was able to figure out some additional information:

- Red Circle over purple background circle is **#d75866**
- Red Circle over human figure is **#ff7f7f**

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to find the hex color and transparency of the red circle"*

The hue (or pure color, without shading, etc) of the pixel is its highest component (with R, G, or B).

Assuming a pixel's RGB has this setup: `AA` = **R**, `BB` = **G**, `CC` = **B**...
And could be presented as `#AABBCC` or `#CCBBAA` depending on color model used, etc.

**Find hex of Red color**: 
To find "Red" you want a pixel with a high **AA** component value when compared to **BB** and **CC** components. The level of Red channel defines the type of Red (*eg:* dark, cherry, rose, etc).

**Find transparency of red circle**:

Given that **AA** is the highest component (Red) you then minus from it, the lowest value from either **BB** or **CC**.

```
Opacity_estimate = ( AA - ( Math.min( BB , CC ) ) );
```

**example:**

> *"Red Circle over purple background circle is `#d75866`"*

The highest is `0xD7` (int: 215) and the lowest is `0x58` (int: 88).

If you do: `215 - 88` then opacity = **127**.
(Or at leasr you can ascertain that the Red level is 128, and that number could be due to lightness or could be due to transparency over a white background).